# Input search filter not working on angular2

Tags: angular2-pipe

I'm facing with the following error  :

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./UserComponent class UserComponent - inline template:217:14 caused by: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

It's just a list of users with a search input page.
The template is the following :

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users | sUser: TxtSearch">
            <td>{{user.userid}}</td>
            <td>{{user.username}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.fullname}}</td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-warning btn-circle-sm" (click)="showEditUser(i, user._id,user)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-circle-sm" (click)="showRemoveUser(user._id, user.username)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

The Search input button is :

```
<div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
<input type="text" class="form-control rounded" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="TxtSearch">
```

And the pipe is :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sUser'
})
export class UserPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
     if(args === undefined || args === '') return value;
    return value.filter(function(val){
      return val.username.toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase());
    });
  }

}
```

And pipe/filter declaration is  in the app.module

What's wrong with the toLowerCase() function in the pipe ? do I need to import something else  ?
Any idea ?

Thank you

/Koul

Answer (score 0):

Change your tranform function and modify passing value type to 'any [] '. hope it helps

```
 transform(value: any[], args?: any): any {
    if(args === undefined || args === '') 
     return value;
   return value.filter(function(val){
       return val.username.toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase());
     });
   }
```

Comment: for some reason , it works without changing a single line of code. How I don't know !!

Answer (score 0):

If you actually read the error you'd know that `val.username` is `undefined`. So simply include a check for it before trying to call `toLowerCase()`. You can also add a safety check for `args`:

```
  transform(value: any[], args?: any): any[] {

    if(args === undefined || args === '') return value;

    return value.filter(function(val) {

      if (!val.username || !args) return false;

      return val.username.toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
```